Showing a function satisfying a certain differential inequality must always be positive
Suppose that
$$f''(t)+cf(t) \geq |f(t)|^p$$
for $t\geq0$, where $c>0$ and $p>1$, $f \in C^2([0, \infty))$, and we know also that $f(0)>0$ and $f'(0)>0$. Is it true that $f(t)\geq 0$ for all $t\geq 0$? At first I thought this should be true but now am much less sure and can't find a counterexample. If you try for a contradiction, and suppose $f$ crosses the axis at some $t_0$, I can see that here $f''(t_0) \geq 0$ but this brings no contradiction as it could still be the case that $f'(t_0)<0$ here. I can see how it would work if $c \leq f(0)^{p-1}$ as then it would also be true that $f''(0)\geq0$, but when you don't have this condition I'm not sure it's true. Thank you in advance for any help.

Consider $f(t):=(\cos^2(t)+\sin(2t))/2$. Then $f(0)=1/2$, $f'(0)=1$, and $f$ takes negative values. Now
$$
f'(t)=\frac{1}{2}(-2\cos(t)\sin(t)+ 2\cos(2t)),
$$
$$
f''(t)=\frac{1}{2}(2-4\cos^2(t)-4\sin(2t))= 1-2\cos^2(t)-2\sin(2t),
$$
hence
$$
f''(t)+4f(t)= 1-2\cos^2(t)-2\sin(2t) + 2\cos^2(t) + 2\sin(2t)=1
$$
$$
\ge \left|\frac{1}{2}(\cos^2(t)+\sin(2t))\right| =|f(t)|\ge |f(t)|^p \quad (t \ge 0)
$$
for each $p>1$. Note that here the condition $c \le f(0)^{p-1}$ fails, since $4>(1/2)^{p-1}$.

Thank you! Great answer. Very small point but $f(0)=\frac{1}{2}$, which doesn't change the solution or the condition on $c$. For my own knowledge, how did you construct this? Did you look at solutions to $f'' + cf' = a$ and just try to adjust the constants so that the solution was definitely negative in places and less than $1$ in magnitude?

@brighton I have corrected the value of $f(0)$, thanks. Indeed, I tried to find nonpositive solutions of $f''+cf=1$ with $|f| \le 1$, so that $|f|^p\le |f|\le 1$.

Yeah that makes sense. Thanks again for your help!
